# "I will come now" Is this a proper way to say that I will soon be there?

Tags: sentence-construction

When I speak in English, translating from my mother tongue, I tend to use the sentence "I will come now" quite a lot. But I  never came across a native speaker using this in any English videos. Could you please let me know if this is a valid sentence (commonly used) and if not could you please suggest an alternative which would sound more natural?

Comment: Whether or not *I will come now* means *I will soon be there* depends entirely on the expected journey time (and the context-specific implications of "soon"). Speaker might be about to leave home to catch a train to the airport, but not arrive at his destination for another day or two.

Comment: Maybe adding some context would clarify things. Most people speaking my mother tongue would say I will come now when they are doing something, for example preparing food in the kitchen when somebody calls the person for some immediate help. Example: A: Have you seen my keys?
B: Wait, I will come now.

Comment: As per @James' answer, we say ***I'm coming!*** if we're within earshot of addressee (in another room in the same house, for example). But that's for *very imminent* arrival - if you're *traveling* to get somewhere, ***I'm on my way*** is more likely.

Comment: “I’m coming!” or just “Coming!” is also very commonly used from inside the house when someone rings the door bell, to indicate to the person at the door that you are  on your way to open the door. And worth noting in addition to @FumbleFingers’ comment: if someone calls you and you say, “(I’m) coming!” and start moving towards them, and they then call you _again_ before you get there – then you would _either_ repeat yourself and say, “Yeah yeah, I’m coming!”, _or_ you could say, “I’m on my way!”, even though you’re not actually ‘travelling’, just going from one room in the house to another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd be more likely to say "I'm coming".  If you are doing it "now" you don't need a future tense, present continuous is more appropriate. And if you use present continuous, you don't need "now" except for emphasis.

So a short and natural utterance is "I'm coming".

Of course the fact you are coming means you will arrive at the end of your journey, which might be very short, or might be long. In context people would understand if this implies you will arrive soon.

Comment: Yes I'm coming sounds better. Thanks a lot for the help.